# Python Program Working In Terminal But Not When Made Into EXE Using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've made a program that will create a directory of pre made files and folders for various HTML based websites.

Python program works fine when launched form VS Code but as soon as I turn it into a .exe with pyinstaller it says template can not be found "an error expression I made print".

It creates the folder structure but does not create the .css, .html, or .js files into there assigned folders. I think I have narrowed it down to it being something with my file path changing somehow when an .exe is created.

I think the problem lies somewhere in the:

```
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    template_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'FileRes')
```

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
def createBasicStructure(self, projName):
        # create our dir structure
        try:
            os.makedirs(self.location.get() + '/' + projName)
            print("Directory " , projName ,  " Created ")
        except FileExistsError:
            print("Directory " , projName ,  " already exists")

        if not os.path.exists(self.location.get() + '/' + projName):
            print("Directory " , projName ,  " no such directory")
        else:    
            os.makedirs(self.location.get() + '/' + projName + '/assets/images')
            os.makedirs(self.location.get() + '/' + projName + '/css')
            os.makedirs(self.location.get() + '/' + projName + '/scripts')
            os.makedirs(self.location.get() + '/' + projName + '/res')

        input_files = ['basic.html', 'css/basic.css', 'scripts/basic.js']
        BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
        template_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'FileRes')
        
        for file in input_files:
            try:
                # Copy sample file
                input_file = open(template_path + '/' + file, 'r')
                content = input_file.read()
                input_file.close()
                # Write content
                try:
                    path = self.location.get() + '/' + projName + '/' + file
                    print(path)
                    output_file = open(path, 'w')
                    output_file.write(content)
                    output_file.close()                   
                    # print('\nfile:', path, '\nsuccessfully created')
                except:
                    print('\nFile could not be written')
            except:
                # new Err
                print('\nTemplate file could not be found')
```

Comment: The actual exception traceback/error message would be very useful... also have you looked at using the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/shutil.html) module? It can probably perform this copy operation your program is doing via the open/read/close & open/write/close file operations. (To that point, see [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/context-managers-in-python-go-beyond-with-open-as-file-85a27e392114) about using the `with` statement for file operations, and context managers in Python)

Answer (score 0):

Had to change

```
       BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
                          
                           to 

       BASE_DIR = os.getcwd()
```

in order for it to read starting from the working directory regardless of py files location or the PC the program is running from.